# DateHistogram with Stacked / Percentile layout

Tags: plotting, histograms, charts

#### Requirements

- Each bin's bars stack to 1.
- Nice Date axes labels and maximal support for DateHistogram features/options.

#### Example

```
data = Table[RandomDate[], {3}, {10}]
```

[image]

Plot like this but Date based: [233507](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/233507/5478)

Comment: I have something I will post but I am not happy with it so I will wait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data1 = RandomChoice[DateRange[{2010, 1, 1}, {2010, 12, 31}, "Day"], 2000];
data2 = RandomChoice[DateRange[{2010, 3, 1}, {2010, 11, 30}, "Day"], 2000];
data3 = RandomChoice[DateRange[{2010, 2, 1}, {2010, 10, 30}, "Day"], 1000];

dh = DateHistogram[{data1, data2, data3}, 
    ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

**1.** We can extract the bar heights, modify them and use the modified heights as custom height specification in the third argument of `DateHistogram`:

```
heights = Reap[DateHistogram[{data1, data2, data3}, Automatic, Sow[#2] &]][[2, 1]];

hl = Transpose[ Normalize[#, Total] & /@ Transpose[heights]];

DateHistogram[{data1, data2, data3}, 
  Automatic, (Last[hl = RotateLeft[hl]] &), ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image]

**2.** We can use a custom `ChartElementFunction` that modifies the coordinates of rectangles:

```
ClearAll[assoc, box, cEF]

assoc = Association[Join @@ Values[
     GroupBy[Reap[DateHistogram[#, ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
      ChartElementFunction -> (ChartElementData["Rectangle"][Sow[#]; ##] &)]][[2, 1]],
      First, Thread[# -> (# /. Thread[#[[All, 2, 2]] -> 
         Normalize[#[[All, 2, 2]], Max]])] &]]] &;

box = assoc[{data1, data2, data3}]; 

cEF = ChartElementData["Rectangle"][box @ #, ##2] &; 
        
DateHistogram[{data1, data2, data3}, 
   ChartLayout -> "Stacked",  ChartElementFunction -> cEF]
```

[image]

**3.** We can post-process `DateHistogram` output produced with the option `ChartLayout -> "Stacked"` to rescale the vertical coordinates of rectangles:

```
ClearAll[reScaleRecs, postProcess]

reScaleRecs = Thread[# -> Rectangle @@@
  SubsetMap[Rescale, List @@@ #[[All, ;; 2]], {All, All, 2}]] &;

postProcess = # /. Flatten[reScaleRecs /@ 
  GatherBy[Cases[#, _Rectangle, All], #[[1, 1]] &]] &;

postProcess @ dh
```

[image]

**Note:** The third method works only for the default chart element function `"Rectangle"`.

Comment: Yep, Sow/Reap is what I had. Thanks. Weird this question was not asked before.